# Script adicionando vários submits ao form no modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, login

Seguinte, estou tentando realizar um formulário de recuperação de senha em um modal, porém, a cada vez que eu clico no botão que abre o modal, um evento de submit é adicionado ao form. Alguma idéia de como posso solucionar esse problema ?

abaixo o código jquery.

```
            // --- -------------- Modal Usuário  -- ------------

                $(document).on("click", "#resetarSenha, #novoUsuario", function(){
                    if($(this).attr('id') == "resetarSenha"){
                        $("#tituloModal").text("Redefinir senha");
                        $('form.form_usuario').attr("id","resetSenha");
                        $("#modalUsuarioBody").html('<div class="form-group">'+
                                                    '<label for="matricula"><strong>Matrícula</strong></label>'+
                                                    '<input type="text" class="form-control mascara" name="matricula" required>'+
                                                    '</div>'+
                                                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                                                        '<label for="senha"><strong>Data de nascimento</strong></label>'+
                                                        '<input id="mascara2" type="text" class="form-control" name="nascimento" required>'+
                                                        '<input type="hidden" name="acao" value="validar"'+
                                                    '</div>');
                        $("#resetSenha").on("submit", function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();

                            var dados = $(this).serialize();
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '../analytics/login/Usuario.php',
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: dados,
                                success: function(data) { 
                                e.preventDefault
                                if (data != ""){
                                    $("#modalUsuarioBody").html(data); 
                                }else{
                                    $("#modalUsuarioBody").append('<div class="alert alert-danger naoEncontrado" role="alert">Usuário não encontrado. Por favor, realize o cadastro.</div>');    
                                    setTimeout(function () {  
                                        $(".naoEncontrado").remove(); 
                                    }, 2000);
                                    //alert(data);
                                }
                                }    
                            })
                        })                           


                    }
                    if($(this).attr('id') == "novoUsuario"){

                        $("#tituloModal").text("Novo usuário");
                        $('form.form_usuario').attr("id", "addUsuario");
                        $("#modalUsuarioBody").html('<div class="form-group">'+
                                                        '<label for="nome"><strong>Nome</strong></label>'+
                                                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" required>'+
                                                    '</div>'+
                                                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                                                        '<label for="matricula"><strong>Matrícula</strong></label>'+
                                                        '<input type="text" class="form-control mascara" name="matricula" required>'+
                                                    '</div>'+
                                                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                                                        '<label for="senha"><strong>Senha</strong></label>'+
                                                        '<input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha" required>'+
                                                    '</div>'+
                                                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                                                        '<label for="senha"><strong>Data de nascimento</strong></label>'+
                                                        '<input id="mascara2" type="text" class="form-control" name="nascimento" required>'+
                                                        '<input type="hidden" name="acao" value="adicionar"'+
                                                    '</div>'); 

                        $("#addUsuario, #resetSenha").on("submit", function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();  
                                var dados = $(this).serialize();
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '../analytics/login/Usuario.php',
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: dados,
                                success: function(data) {                       
                                    classe = null;
                                    if(data == 1) {
                                        msg = "Adicionado com sucesso.";
                                        classe = "alert alert-success"
                                    }else{
                                        msg = "Erro ao adicionar. Usuário já cadastrado."
                                        classe = "alert alert-danger";
                                    }
                                    $("#resultado").removeClass();
                                    $("#resultado").addClass(classe);
                                    $("#resultado").show();
                                    $("#resultado").html(msg);
                                    setTimeout(function () {  
                                        $("#resultado").hide();  
                                    }, 2000);
                                    $('#addUsuario').trigger("reset");
                                },
                                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                                }
                            });
                            return false;
                            });            
                    }
                    mascaraMatricula();
                    mascaraData();            
                })
```

------------------- html dos botões que acionam o modal ----------------

```
                 <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <form id="ajax_auth" action="" class="form-horizontal"  method="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                        <input class="form-control login mascara" type="text" name="login" placeholder="Matrícula" required/>
                        <input class="form-control login" type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required/>
                        <input class="btn btn-primary w-100 mb-1" type="submit" name="submit" value="Entrar" />
                        <div id="resultadoAuth" class="mt-2 p-1" role="alert"></div>
                        <div id="resetarSenha" class="form" style="margin:0 auto"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalUsuario" href="#">Esqueci minha senha</a></div> <!-- Botão que abre o modal -->
                        <div id="novoUsuario" class="form">Novo usuário?   <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalUsuario" href="#">Cadastre-se</a></div>  <!-- O outro botão que abre o mesmo modal -->
                    </form>                                 
                </div>
```

-----------------------  html do form do modal  ---------------------------

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalUsuario"> 
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title text-center" style="margin: 0 auto"><strong id="tituloModal"></strong></h5>
            </div>
            <form class="form_usuario" action="" method ="" >
                <div id="modalUsuarioBody" class="modal-body"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Sair</button>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O botão está dentro de um `form`? Poste o HTML tb para que possamos analisar.

Comment: Pronto! A minha ideia é fazer com que dependendo do botão que o usuário clicar, apareça as informações com base no objetivo do botão por ajax. Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Coloque também o HTML do form.

Comment: Acho melhor separa o HTML do JS e colocar o scripts fora do modal.

Comment: Pronto. Coloquei o html de ambos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao incluir o evento `submit` dentro do evento `click` você está criando várias instâncias cada vez que abre a modal.

Neste caso você precisa fazer 2 coisas:

**1)** Colocar os eventos `submit` fora dos eventos `click`, ou seja, cada coisa separada:

```
$("seletor").on("submit", function(){ ... });
$("seletor").on("click", function(){ ... });
```

**2)** Usar delegação nos seletores. Em vez de:

```
$("#resetSenha").on("submit", function(e){...
```

Usar:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#resetSenha", function(e){
```

Faça isso isso em todos os eventos `submit`.

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Ajudou demais.